# How to add a palette to geom_smooth and remove grey background in legends?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a  fitted plot using ggplot2. With `geom_smooth()`, the fitted lines are blue in color. I tried by adding `color = "black"` into the geom_smooth. You can see that lines were changed to black, but i still see grey background in the legend area. In the first I would like to remove that grey background or increase the width for better representation of dotted lines in legend area and second I would like to add `"npg"` color or different color palette of my interest to it.  Can anyone help to fix these issues. Here is the code

```
df<-data.frame(y=rnorm(200,30,20),x=rnorm(200,20,10),treat=factor(rbinom(100,1,0.5)))

p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, group=treat))+
          geom_point(size = 2)+
          geom_smooth(aes(linetype=treat), color = "black")+
          labs(x ="tf", y = "xm") +
          theme_bw() +
          scale_linetype_manual(values=c( "solid", "dashed"),
          labels = c("1", "2"))
p1
```

Comment: I wonder if [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33779219/cannot-remove-grey-area-behind-legend-symbol-when-using-smooth) helps you.

Comment: Thank you. I am still looking how to add "npg" color.

Comment: What is npg color?

Comment: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/hdnom/versions/5.0/topics/palette.npg       @ camille

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way to do it using two `stat_smooth` calls. The first one draws the line only, the second one includes the se but omits the legend:

```
          geom_smooth(aes(linetype=treat), color='black', se=FALSE)+
          geom_smooth(aes(linetype=treat), color='black', show.legend=FALSE)+
```

credit: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/zEIKqD-QeoY

Comment: Thank you Kent. Also in the legend is there any way I can increase the width for dashed and dotted lines, so that in the dotted lines legend, I can show atleast two dotted lines. Another thing is how can I added "npg" color or a color palette to it

Comment: To change the legend width use `theme()` to set `legend.key.width`, e.g. `theme(legend.key.width=unit(2, 'cm'))`

Comment: I don't understand your question about color. Generally, you should assign a `color` aesthetic in the geom, then use one of the `scale_color_xxx` functions to control the palette.

Comment: Thank you kent. I will assign color aes in the geom.